# To extract the id of the field using the name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am developing a basic MVC application. I have three tables,

```
Customer(cId,cName)
Product(pId,pName,price)
Invoice(iId,cId,pId,quantity)
```

Where cId,pId are the foreign keys.

I created a basic display page for the Invoice table by using the provided scaffolding in MVC to display Product Name,Customer Name,Price,Quantity.

But in order to add a new invoice, the provided code on click of Create new wants the details to be productId,customer Id.
I want the user to be able to enter Customer and Product Names and display them on the screen.So how do I go about having product name and customer name in the front end while capturing their product id to display the Price?

Comment: Use a dropdownlist to display and select the customer and product

Comment: @StephenMuecke Is it possible to have product Name as the display and product id as the value?

Comment: Yes. You can generate the `SelectList` using `var CustomerList = new SelectList(db.Customers, "cId", "cName");` and when used in `@Html.DropDownList()` it will display the `cName` value, but bind to the `cId` value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this.
for product details you can use dropdown list that show text as product name and value as id of product

example

```
List<SelectListItem> productlist= new List<SelectListItem>();

     items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "fridge", Value = "0"});

     items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "AC", Value = "1" });

     items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "TV", Value = "2", Selected = true });
 ViewBag.productlist= items;
```

and on view write like this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.products, ViewBag.productlist as List<SelectListItem>,htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control"})
```

for customer

you can use

```
<input type="hidden" name="customer" value="customerid" />
```